# How to add "custom addon folder" in odoo

Tags: odoo

I downloaded odoo 13 (windows) from https://www.odoo.com/page/download then i opened the files on pycharm and made a new directory,named custom_addons under odoo folder but when i updated app list i searched the module but didnt find that then i pasted that module under by default addons folder i found my module. Why i was unable to get my custom module when i added that on my cystom_addons folder ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `.conf` file you need to add the path of the custom addon folder.

For in detail reference, find any of the following links:

Link 1: https://www.getopenerp.com/install-odoo-12-on-ubuntu-18-04/

Link 2: https://www.cybrosys.com/blog/how-to-install-odoo-12-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: Thanks . But the module i created in custom is not shown ... however when i create the module in addons folder it was shown in apps... any idea ? Where i am wrong

Comment: Hi Wania Kanwal, Have you update app list After adding your custom app?

Comment: I updated but when i added the module in custom addons folders it was not shown but when i added module in default addons folder it was shown after adding updating list

Comment: @WaniaKanwal this should answer your question, could you edit your question and show how are you running your Odoo,  and the full path of your costum module

Answer (score 0):

For everyone that have the same issue in 2020, in addition you need to stop and start the odoo server before updating the app list.